# LazyColum lags jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have ComposableScreen(NewsScreen) where i draw news for user. I do request from repository, when ViewModel init. News can be PersonPost or GroupPost.
I dont know why LazyColumn lags

> NewsViewModel

```
class NewsViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _loadState = MutableStateFlow(LoadState())
    val loadState: StateFlow<LoadState> = _loadState.asStateFlow()

    private val _posts = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Item>())
    val post = _posts.asStateFlow()

    private val _profiles = MutableStateFlow(HashMap<Int, Profile>())
    val profiles = _profiles.asStateFlow()

    private val _groups = MutableStateFlow(HashMap<Int, Group>())
    val groups = _groups.asStateFlow()

    private val newsRepository = NewsRepository()
    private val postRepository = PostRepository()

    private val dispatcherIo = Dispatchers.IO

    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        _loadState.value = LoadState(isError = true)
        Log.d("NewsViewModel", "Error: ${throwable.message}")
    }

    init {
        requestNews()
    }

    fun requestNews() {
        _loadState.value = LoadState(isLoading = true)

        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIo + exceptionHandler) {
            val response: Deferred<Response<Posts>> = async(dispatcherIo) {
                newsRepository.getNews("post")
            }
            response.await()

            val result = response.getCompleted().body()!!.response

            setProperties(result)
            _loadState.value = LoadState(isLoading = false)
        }
    }

    private fun setProperties(result: com.example.vkfuture.data.model.modelnews.Response) {
        _posts.value = result.items

        result.groups.forEach {
            _groups.value[it.id] = it
        }

        result.profiles.forEach {
            _profiles.value[it.id] = it
        }
    }

    fun userLikeChanged(status: Int, type: String, itemId: String, ownerId: String) {

        if (status == 1) {
            viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIo + exceptionHandler) {
                postRepository.addLike(type, itemId, ownerId)
            }
        } else {
            viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherIo + exceptionHandler) {
                postRepository.deleteLike(type, itemId, ownerId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> NewsScreen(composable)

```
@Composable
fun NewsScreen(newsViewModel: NewsViewModel = viewModel(), navController: NavController) {

    val state by newsViewModel.loadState.collectAsState()
    val posts by newsViewModel.post.collectAsState()
    val profiles by newsViewModel.profiles.collectAsState()
    val groups by newsViewModel.groups.collectAsState()

    MaterialTheme {
        SetScreen(newsViewModel, state, posts, profiles, groups, navController)
    }

}

@Composable
private fun SetScreen(
    newsViewModel: NewsViewModel,
    state: LoadState,
    posts: List<Item>,
    profiles: HashMap<Int, Profile>,
    groups: HashMap<Int, Group>,
    navController: NavController
) {
    val refresh = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing = false)
    SwipeRefresh(state = refresh, onRefresh = { newsViewModel.requestNews() }) {

        if (state.isLoading) {
            LoadingScreen()
        } else if (state.isError) {
            ErrorScreen()
        } else {
            SetPosts(posts, profiles, groups, newsViewModel, navController)
            AddPostButton(navController)
        }
    }


}

@Composable
private fun LoadingScreen() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ErrorScreen() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        Snackbar(Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp, end = 5.dp, bottom = 30.dp)) {
            Text("Ошибка загрузки", fontSize = 22.sp)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun AddPostButton(navController: NavController) {
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(1f)) {
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = { navController.navigate("createPost") },
            Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "Добавить пост")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SetPosts(
    posts: List<Item>,
    profiles: HashMap<Int, Profile>,
    groups: HashMap<Int, Group>,
    newsViewModel: NewsViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {

    LazyColumn(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
        items(count = posts.size, key = { posts[it].id }, itemContent = { index ->
            val postData = posts[index]
            if (postData.owner_id > 0) {
                PersonPost(postData, profiles, newsViewModel, navController)
            } else {
                GroupPost(postData, groups, newsViewModel, navController)
            }
        })
    }
}

@Composable
private fun PersonPost(
    post: Item,
    profiles: HashMap<Int, Profile>,
    newsViewModel: NewsViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {
    val profile = profiles[post.owner_id]
    val name = "${profile?.first_name}  ${profile?.last_name}"
    val image = profile?.photo_100
    Post(post = post, name = name, photo = image, newsViewModel, post.owner_id, navController)
}

@Composable
private fun GroupPost(
    post: Item,
    groups: HashMap<Int, Group>,
    newsViewModel: NewsViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {
    val group = groups[post.owner_id * -1]
    val name = group?.name
    val image = group?.photo_100
    Post(post = post, name = name, photo = image, newsViewModel, post.owner_id, navController)
}
```

> Post(Composable)

```
@Composable
fun Post(
    post: Item,
    name: String?,
    photo: String?,
    newsViewModel: NewsViewModel,
    owner_id: Int,
    navController: NavController
) {
    var isDropdownState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isBottomSheetVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                //shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 12.dp)
            )
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(12.dp)
                .height(48.dp)
        ) {
            OwnerDetails(photo, name, post, owner_id, navController)
            MenuPost(isDropdownState)
        }
        TextPost(post)
        ImagesPost(post)
        Row(Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
            BottomButtons(post, newsViewModel, isBottomSheetVisible)
            Views(post)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun OwnerDetails(
    photo: String?,
    name: String?,
    post: Item,
    owner_id: Int,
    navController: NavController
) {
    Row(Modifier.clickable {
        if (owner_id < 0) navController.navigate("group/$owner_id") else navController.navigate(
            "profile/$owner_id"
        )
    }) {
        AsyncImage(
            /* painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),*/
            model = photo,
            contentDescription = "Avatar",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(48.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape),
        )

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .padding(start = 8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                name ?: "",
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                maxLines = 1,
                modifier = Modifier.widthIn(max = 224.dp)
            )
            Text(
                convertUnix(post.date),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                fontSize = 12.sp
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MenuPost(_isDropdownState: Boolean) {
    var isDropdownState by remember { mutableStateOf(_isDropdownState) }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 24.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
    ) {
        IconButton(onClick = {
            isDropdownState = true
        }) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.MoreVert, contentDescription = "Больше")
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = isDropdownState,
            onDismissRequest = { isDropdownState = false }) {
            DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("А ПОЧЕМУ") }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
            DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Я ВСЕГДА") }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
            DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("ДЕЛАЮ ВСЁ") }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
            DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("ПОЗДНО НОЧЬЮ") }, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TextPost(post: Item) {
    var textLen by remember { mutableStateOf(4) }
    var textShowMore by remember { mutableStateOf(R.string.showMore) }
    val modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 12.dp, end = 12.dp)


    Text(
        text = post.text,
        modifier = modifier,
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        maxLines = textLen,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )


    Text(
        stringResource(textShowMore),
        modifier = modifier.clickable {
            if (textShowMore == R.string.showMore) {
                textShowMore = R.string.hide
                textLen = Int.MAX_VALUE

            } else {
                textShowMore = R.string.showMore
                textLen = 4
            }
        },
        fontSize = 16.sp,
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun ImagesPost(post: Item) {
    val images = remember { mutableStateListOf<Attachment>() }
    post.attachments.forEach {
        if (it.photo != null) images.add(it)
    }
    HorizontalPager(images.size, Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
        AsyncImage(
            images[it].photo.sizes[getHighestResPhoto(images[it].photo.sizes)].url,
            "Photo $it",
            placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun BottomButtons(
    post: Item,
    newsViewModel: NewsViewModel,
    _isBottomSheetVisible: Boolean
) {
    var isBottomSheetVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(_isBottomSheetVisible) }

    var isUserLiked by remember { mutableStateOf(post.likes.user_likes) }
    var likesCount by remember { mutableStateOf(post.likes.count) }
    TextIconButton(
        likesCount.toString(),
        Icons.Outlined.FavoriteBorder,
        isUserLiked == 1
    ) {
        if (isUserLiked == 1) {
            isUserLiked = 0; likesCount -= 1; post.likes.user_likes =
                0; post.likes.count -= 1
        } else {
            isUserLiked = 1; likesCount += 1; post.likes.user_likes =
                1; post.likes.count += 1
        }

        newsViewModel.userLikeChanged(
            isUserLiked,
            post.type,
            post.id.toString(),
            post.owner_id.toString()
        )
    }

    Spacer(Modifier.width(8.dp))

    TextIconButton(
        post.comments.count.toString(),
        Icons.Outlined.MailOutline
    ) { Log.d("PICTURES", post.attachments.toString()) }

    Spacer(Modifier.width(8.dp))

    TextIconButton(
        post.reposts.count.toString(),
        Icons.Outlined.Send
    ) { isBottomSheetVisible = true }

    if (isBottomSheetVisible) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { isBottomSheetVisible = false },
            Modifier.padding()
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = {},
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                placeholder = { Text("Поиск диалогов") },
                leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, "Поиск диалогов") })
            LazyRow() {
                items(5) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.gosha),
                        contentDescription = "Avatar",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(56.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape),
                    )
                }
            }
            TextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = {},
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                placeholder = { Text("Сообщение") },
                leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Outlined.MailOutline, "Сообщение") })
            LazyRow() {
                items(5) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                        contentDescription = "Avatar",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(56.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Views(post: Item) {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd) {
        Row(Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Person, "Просмотры")
            Spacer(Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing))
            Text(post.views.count.toString())
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun TextIconButton(
    text: String,
    icon: ImageVector,
    used: Boolean = false,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {

    FilledTonalButton(
        onClick = {
            onClick.invoke()
        },
        Modifier.defaultMinSize(minWidth = 1.dp, minHeight = 1.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        colors = if (used) ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer) else ButtonDefaults.buttonColors()
    ) {
        Icon(icon, "", Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSize))
        Spacer(Modifier.size(4.dp))
        Text(text, maxLines = 1)
    }

}

private fun convertUnix(time: Int): String { // TODO: ВЫНЕСТИ КУДА-НИБУДЬ
    val date = Date(time.toLong() * 1000)
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM kk:mm", Locale.getDefault())
    return dateFormat.format(date)
}

private fun getHighestResPhoto(photos: List<Size>): Int {
    var max_size = 0
    var index = 0
    photos.forEachIndexed { itemIndex, element ->
        if (element.height * element.width > max_size) {
            max_size = element.height * element.width
            index = itemIndex
        }
    }
    return index
}
```

I have tried replace LazyColumn to Column, and it works fine. But I think it is not good to use Column for more 50 items

Comment: You are using ```.clickable{}``` inside the bottom most component which causes the recomposition of whole ```LazyColumn```.

https://medium.com/@patilshreyas/solving-the-mystery-of-recompositions-in-composes-lazylist-514d187079b9

Comment: @ChiragThummar i dont understand you. I have lags when i scroll lazyColumn, any .clickable are not invoking.

Comment: Did you refer the attached link?. your lazycolumn may lag due to overly recomposition of the item.